# Exception in String to date conversion

Tags: java

whats wrong in parsing the date Thu 10 July 2013 using below code

```
Date parse = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE d M yyyy").parse("Thu 10 July 2013");
```

it is working for

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE M yyyy").parse("Thu July 2013");
```

but if i put day (d) in the string then its throwing following exception

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE d M yyyy").parse("Thu 10 July 2013");

java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu 10 July 2013"
```

Thanks inadvance

Comment: `new SimpleDateFormat("EEE M yyyy").parse("Thu July 2013")` doesn't actually work for me, it throws an `Unparseable date: "Thu July 2013"` exception

Comment: new SimpleDateFormat("EEE M yyyy").parse("Thu July 2013"); Doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dd` instead of `d` and also MMM instead of MM:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd MMM yyyy").parse("Thu 10 July 2013");
```

Comment: "Technically" `dd` isn't required for this to work ;)

Comment: but that's not the case. d or dd, the problem is using M.

Answer (score 3):

Try expanding your format to something like `EEE d MMMM yyyy`

A single or double `M` will be interrupted as the numerical month value (ie `{0}7`), `MMM` will be interrupted as the short month name (ie `Jul`) and `MMMM` will be interrupted as the full month name (ie `July`)

It should also be noted that in my testing `MMM` and `MMMM` seemed to work

Answer (score 0):

I tried and

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE d M yyyy").parse("Thu 10 July 2013");
```

doesn't work hence I changed the month format to `MMMM`

```
Date parse = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMMM yyyy").parse("Thu July 2013");
Date p1 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE d MMMM yyyy").parse("Thu 10 July 2013");
System.out.println(p1);
```

This is working.

Answer (score 0):

I try this but it cause runtime exception

```
java.util.Date  dt = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE M yyyy").parse("Thu July 2013");
```

According to the java docs [Oracle Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

If you want to pars date string with month name like **July** or **Jul** you should use **MMMM** or **MMM** respectively.

If you want to parse date that contain **number of month** you can use **M** or **MM**.e.g. ("28 8 2012")

For your case you should use **MMM or MMMM** instead of M.like this

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE d MMM yyyy").parse("Thu 10 July 2013");
```

or

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE d MMMM yyyy").parse("Thu 10 July 2013") ;
```